# Custom Metrics API service install for kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, prometheus, amazon-eks

We are planning to Kubernetes horizontal pod scheduler and for that need to install Custom Metrics API.
Can someone please tell different ways to install Custom Metrics API on kubernetes cluster?

Comment: You have used terraform, GKE and EKS tags. You need to provide more details about your environment. Are you want to use GKE with Stackdriver or Prometheus or EKS with other apps. Most of the information you will find in specific cloud provider docs or Kubernetes documentation. Please provide more details what exactly you want to achieve and on what environment.

Comment: @PjoterS We are using EKS with prometheus,I am trying to register custom metrics API service.We use helm as package manager for kubernetes.Do i need prometheus adaptor for registering custom metrics API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using EKS with [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/), the best source of knowledge is AWS documentation.

> Do i need prometheus adaptor for registering custom metrics API?

Yes, you need at least `Prometheus` and [Prometheus Adapter](https://github.com/stefanprodan/eks-hpa-profile/blob/master/monitoring-system/prometheus-adapter.yaml).

- `Prometheus:` scrapes pods and stores metrics
- `Prometheus metrics adapter:` queries `Prometheus` and exposes metrics for the Kubernetes custom metrics API
- `Metrics server:` collects pods CPU and memory usage and exposes metrics for the Kubernetes resource metrics API

Without `Custom Metrics` or `External Metrics`, you can only use metrics based on `CPU` or `Memory`.

In [Autoscaling Amazon EKS services based on custom Prometheus metrics using CloudWatch Container Insights](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/autoscaling-amazon-eks-services-based-on-custom-prometheus-metrics-using-cloudwatch-container-insights/) article, it's stated:

> The custom metrics gathered by Prometheus can be exposed to the autoscaler using a `Prometheus Adapter` as outlined in the blog post titled [Autoscaling EKS on Fargate with custom metrics](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/autoscaling-eks-on-fargate-with-custom-metrics/).

In `Autoscaling EKS on Fargate with custom metrics` blog you also find some examples of `autoscaling based on CPU usage`, `autoscaling based on App Mesh traffic` or `autoscaling based on HTTP traffic`

**Additional documentation**

- [Control plane metrics with Prometheus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/prometheus.html)
- [Why can't I collect metrics from containers, pods, or nodes using Metrics Server in Amazon EKS?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-metrics-server/)
- [Install the CloudWatch agent with Prometheus metrics collection on Amazon EKS and Kubernetes clusters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights-Prometheus-Setup.html)